# Android Get Apps Adaptive Icons from Package Manager

Tags: android, icons

I'm getting apps launcher icons like this

```
resolveInfo.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
```

But in Android 8.0 Oreo, this line returning empty icon to me because of adaptive icons. How can i retrieve apps adaptive icons? Thank you..

Comment: Any ideas about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this class to get bitmap from adaptiveIcon.

```
public static class AppIconHelperV26 {

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static Bitmap getAppIcon(PackageManager mPackageManager, String packageName) {

        try {
            Drawable drawable = mPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName);

            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            } else if (drawable instanceof AdaptiveIconDrawable) {
                Drawable backgroundDr = ((AdaptiveIconDrawable) drawable).getBackground();
                Drawable foregroundDr = ((AdaptiveIconDrawable) drawable).getForeground();

                Drawable[] drr = new Drawable[2];
                drr[0] = backgroundDr;
                drr[1] = foregroundDr;

                LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(drr);

                int width = layerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int height = layerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                layerDrawable.draw(canvas);

                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have last versions of SDK tools in sdk manager. But AdaptiveIconDrawable class is not resolving

Comment: change compilesdkversion to 26 in your gradle

Comment: @VishnuPrasad Is there a way to clip the adaptive icons in a specific shape? Thanks in advance