# The icon obtained in 'applicationinfo' is different from the actual desktop icon

Tags: android, application-icon, adaptive-icon

Trying to show application icon in my app. Firstly, i used `Application.loadIcon()`. That worked fine until an application 'lark' used `AdaptiveIconDrawable`, which crashed my app. The exception said `AdaptiveIconDrawable` can't be cast to `BitmapDrawable`. So I changed the way to get icon bitmap which is same the method in the post:
[Android Get Apps Adaptive Icons from Package Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130594/android-get-apps-adaptive-icons-from-package-manager)

But another problem apearred, the icon obtaind in this way is different with the application's real desktop icon
Icon I obtained:
[Obtained Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ndnK.png)

Actual desktop Icon:
[Real Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUNRs.png)