How to get an apps icon as a square instead of rounded?
(Running this on a Google Pixel 7a, running Android 14)
I am working on a launcher application, and I need to be able to display launcher icons as square.
However, whenever I draw the icon, it is always rounded, even if the app does not have any rounded icon in its resources.
How can I obtain the full icon, without it being rounded into a circle?
This is my current code:
var pm = context.getPackageManager()

var mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

var apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0)
for (resolveInfo in apps) { 
    val iconDrawable = resolveInfo.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm)
            
    var img = ImageView(context)
    img.setImageDrawable(icon)

    appGrid.addView(img) // always displays as a circle
}


have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130594/android-get-apps-adaptive-icons-from-package-manager ?

You can't control this. This is system control.

Thanks to @Pawel for pointing this out.
A solution to my problem was already found here.
For anyone who might need this in the future, here is the answer that was posted there, translated into Kotlin:
fun getAppIcon(packageManager: PackageManager, packageName: String): Bitmap? {
    try {
        var drawable = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)

        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            return drawable.getBitmap()
        } else if (drawable is AdaptiveIconDrawable) {
            var backgroundDr = drawable.getBackground()
            var foregroundDr = drawable.getForeground()
            var drr = arrayOf(backgroundDr, foregroundDr)
            var layerDrawable: LayerDrawable = LayerDrawable(drr)
                
            var width = layerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()
            var height = layerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()

            var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            var canvas: Canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

            layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight())
            layerDrawable.draw(canvas)

            return bitmap
        }
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
    return null
}

